# Print certain value inside <td>

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to print certain value that it's inside a `<td>` .
The values I get from a webpage and they look like this:

```
  <b>General Information</b>
  <table width="400">
      <tr>
          <td>Hostname</td>
          <td>jade.nephrite.ro - Quest special | Roata Norocului</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gamemode</td>
          <td>nephrite, 04 Mar 2019 14:52:55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Players</td>
          <td>330 / 1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Map</td>
          <td>RO/EN</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Weather</td>
          <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>23:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Version</td>
          <td>0.3.7-R2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td>No</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <br />
  <b>Online Players</b>
  <br /><i>None</i>
```

I am trying to print only `<td>330 / 1000</td>` that's under `<td>Players</td>`. I tried many ways that I could find on google but sadly none worked for me as I don't have that much experience in python and couldn't edit the code so that works for my table.

Current code:

```
import requests

url = "http://crowned.ro/api/test.php"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
infos = response.text
#infos = response.json()
print(infos.find("Players"))
#print(infos['[Players]'])
```

Comment: show your current code

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski , current code has been added.

Comment: You'll want to start by installing and reading up a little bit on: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: Then once you've got it soup'ified... something like: `soup.find('td', text='Players').find_next_sibling('td').text` should give you: `'330 / 1000'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jon-clements, I looked thorugh BeautifulSoup4 and learned a bit how to use it.
The solution is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(infos, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('td', text='Players').find_next_sibling('td').text)
```

so everything looks like this now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://crowned.ro/api/test.php?sv=jade.nephrite.ro"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
infos = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(infos, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('td', text='Players').find_next_sibling('td').text)
```

Comment: Glad it helped... thanks very much for taking the time to post a self-answer with the solution.